# Upload to document library on another site causes error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

Using SharePoint 2013 Enterprise, on-prem.

I have a document library on Site A, which has a metadata column "Field A".

I want to put a link (URL) on Site B to allow users to upload a file to the library on Site A.

If I create a link to the URL like:

https://myportal/SiteA/_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List={D0DF652C-CCC7-4695-9349-3592A72CA09C}&RootFolder=

on Site A, where the document library exists, it works fine. It lets me browse and select a file, then it displays the EditForm.aspx page to allow me to specify the metadata column value.

However, when I put a link to the same URL on Site B, it allows me to browse and select the file, but when I click OK, instead of displaying EditForm.aspx to allow entry of the metadata column, I get:

Sorry, something went wrong 
Incorrect function. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070001)

Any ideas why this might not work, or a way to accomplish this in another way?

Comment: I suspect this is because the Upload.aspx page code is site specific and since you're coming from another site, the execution context doesn't match this generating the error. You can get the Correlation IS from the error and check the ULS logs for more details.

Comment: I agree. The ULS log shows the stack trace below. I suppose the question then is how can I get it to generate a new context. I really don't want to try to reproduce an upload function myself.
-----
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetList(String strUrl)     at Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.PolicyFeatures.ApplicationPages.UploadExPage.get_IsSourceUrlDocumentLibrary()     at Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.PolicyFeatures.ApplicationPages.UploadExPage.get_SourceUrl()     at Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.PolicyFeatures.ApplicationPages.UploadExPage.GetEditFormUrl(SPFile spfile)